# Update TetxView on the running activity from a Thread that started from MainActivity

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have two Activities. MainActivity and SecondActivity.
MainActiviy has a TextView(tvTXT) and three Buttons(btnSend, btnThread ,btnStartActivity2)
SecondActivity has a TextView(tvTXT) and a Button(btnSend1)

btnThread starts a thread that is changing the tvTXT text when boolean txtUPDATE = true

btnSend and btnSend1 change that boolean to txtUPDATE=true

When the btnSend is pressed its successfully do tvTXT.setText("Value is: "+ x); in MainActity.
When pressing btnStartActivity2 to start SecondActivity and afterwards pressing the btnSend1 the thread started on MainActivity cant tvTXT.setText("Value is: "+ x);in SecondActiviy.

** btnThread starts the thread with the following code on run(): **

```
public void run() {

    while (txtUPDATE){
      MainActivity.thisActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              MainActivity.tvTXT.setText("Value is: "+ x);
               MainActivity.txtUPDATE = false;
          }
      });
    }
```

** btnSend and btnSend1 code **

```
      txtUPDATE = true;
      x++;
```

How can i set TextView(tvTXT) text in SecondActivity from the thread that is started at MainActivity?

Comment: your post in unclear. confusing

Comment: There seems to be a major misunderstanding.

Comment: Can you please explain me what part you dont understand to try to explain it further ? Thank you for your replies..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you try to have something in MainActivity change something in SecondActivity?  The explanation is confusing.  Your runnable is only changing tvTXT in MainActivity, the TextView used in SecondActivity is a completely different object and View instance, so the Runnable will have no ability to change UI components in SecondActivity.

Comment: The reason is that i want the Thread to act as a background service that changes the content of current Activity/View when the boolean changed to true.. If its not possible.. Whats the correct way to do that ? Thank you

Comment: There are a number of ways you can accomplish this.  You could use a custom service implementation which spawns a thread and when an activity goes through onResume it "registers" with the service a callback interface.  Be sure to unregister the activity when it passes through onPause.  You could also have a background thread send a broadcast intent which the foreground activity has registered a receiver in onResume (and subsequently unregistered it in onPause).  There are plenty of other ways as well, these are just 2 quick examples.